# spring how to get BeanFactory from Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I am a beginner in spring.
Today, when I was reading the spring core document, I found the following instructions in chapter 1.3. [Bean Overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition)

> In addition to bean definitions that contain information on how to create a specific bean, the ApplicationContext implementations also permit the registration of existing objects that are created outside the container (by users). This is done by accessing the ApplicationContext’s BeanFactory through the getBeanFactory() method, which returns the BeanFactory DefaultListableBeanFactory implementation. DefaultListableBeanFactory supports this registration through the registerSingleton(..) and registerBeanDefinition(..) methods. However, typical applications work solely with beans defined through regular bean definition metadata.

I instantiated an ApplicationContext object in IDEA with the following code, but I found that this object does not have a `getBeanFactory()` method:

```java
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
```

The document I read is the 5.3.5 version of spring, and I am using the same version of spring.

I guess if spring changed the ApplicationContext class and forgot to modify the document.
Or is there something wrong with the object I instantiated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `ApplicationContext` is the `BeanFactory` and it will delegate to an internal one. You can use `getAutowireCapableBeanFactory` or use the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` instead of `ApplicationContext` to have access to a `getBeanFactory` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to cast it to a ConfigurableApplicationContext.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html